# Java GUI Fill Empty spaces

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

[image: Java GUI]I have the following Java GUI for my project. For some reason, the middle and right panels have been put below leaving empty spaces - marked in red. Is there a way to pull the panels up to fill the spaces.

These empty spaces does not look good. I have tried to check all code but cannot pinpoint where to correct.

Thanks in advance.

```
     public static JPanel main= new JPanel(), 
     left= new JPanel(),middle= new JPanel(),right = new JPanel();

     Container c = getContentPane();     
     c.setLayout(new FlowLayout()) ; 

     JPanel pane = new JPanel();     
     pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());     
     pane.add(new JLabel("Enter word/SQL: "), "North");      
     pane.add(tf, "Center");   //enter keyword       

     JPanel second = new JPanel();       
     second.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 1));                     
     second.add(messageIDText);          

     //This is the start of adding panels        
     //create a left side panal and add the sub panels to it    
     JPanel left = new JPanel();     
     JPanel middle = new JPanel();       
     JPanel center = new JPanel();   
     JTextArea output = new JTextArea("", 60, 60);   
     JPanel sixth = new JPanel(); 
     JPanel seventh = new JPanel();
     JPanel eigth = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,1));     
     JPanel labels7 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));       
     JPanel controls7 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));         
     JPanel tenth = new JPanel();
     sixth.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));

     JPanel fourth = new JPanel();
     fourth.add(firstButton);        
     sixth.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);       
     sixth.add(controls, BorderLayout.CENTER);        
     sixth.add(controlsButtons, BorderLayout.EAST);
     labels.add(new JLabel("Proposal:"));         
     controls.add(proposalNumberText);                
     controlsButtons.add(freeQueryButton);

     //add border
     pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new 
     EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10), BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()));      
     fourth.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new 
     EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10), BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder()));

     //-------LEFT SIDE -- PARAMETERS
     left.setLayout(new BoxLayout(left, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
     JLabel headerLabel,blank;   
     headerLabel = new JLabel("Navigate Records", JLabel.LEFT);  
     Font f = headerLabel.getFont();
     headerLabel.setFont(f.deriveFont(f.getStyle() ^ Font.BOLD)); // bold
     left.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);       
     left.add(fourth, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

     main.add(left);

     //---------MIDDLE PART - Messages - tabbed pane
    JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();        
    getContentPane().add(jtp);
    //jtp.setSize(jtp.getPreferredSize());
    JPanel jpA = new JPanel(),jpB = new JPanel(),
    jpC = new JPanel(),jpD = new JPanel();
    JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(),jp = new 
    JScrollPane(activeTSText), jp2 = new JScrollPane(analyseWordsText),
    jp3 = new JScrollPane(markedMessageText); 
    JLabel labelA = new JLabel();       
    labelA.setText("");     
    jpA.add(labelA);        
    jpA.add(jp);        

    jtp.addTab("Message", jpA);                 
    middle.add(jtp);
    main.add(middle);       

    //----------RIGHT PART -  ..        //paramters and results     
    JPanel  jj = new JPanel();  
    jj.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jj, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    stateJTable.setRowHeight(20);   //add JTable
    JScrollPane js3 =new JScrollPane(stateJTable);       
    js3.setVisible(true);       

    //JTabbedPane jtp2 = new JTabbedPane();         
    //JPanel StateSubstatesTabOnLeft = new JPanel(), 
    StateSubstates_PostProcessedTabOnLeft = new JPanel();       
    JPanel firstleftTabinRightSideOfFrame = new JPanel(), 
    secondLeftTabinRightSideOfFrame = new 
    JPanel(),rightTabInRightSideOfFrame = new JPanel(); 

    jj.add(js3);    
    //downbelow, the state jtable is added to the panel here through the 
    //scrollpane which contains the jtable

    right.add(jj) ; //stateJTable);// add table in panel using add() method
    main.add(right); 
    proposalNumberText.requestFocusInWindow();
```

Comment: Java code is written with a single statement per line. I'm not even going to attempt to read the code posted above until it is properly formatted.

Comment: Structured code.

Comment: 1) Now the code is duplicated twice. 2) the code is not complete so we can't follow the flow of how components are added. 3) So the solution is to start over and create an [mre]. The "MRE" will consist of a frame and your 3 main panels, left, middle, right. Then once the "MRE" works properly, you start adding more components to one panel and make sure it still works. The point is to simplify the problem by making one change at a time. The when it stops working you know exactly what you changed.

Comment: removed duplication

Comment: Point 3 was the important point. You still haven't followed the advice to post the [mre] so there is no much we can do. Problem solving is about learning to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using Borderlayout and assigning the main panel to it.
The assigning the WEST, CENTER and EAST regions to it.

I have added the code below in the code above at places where the main panel is being added to.

Thank you for the advice to start debugging by using MRE approach.

```
BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
main.setLayout(layout); 
main.add(left,BorderLayout.WEST);
main.add(middle,BorderLayout.CENTER);
main.add(right,BorderLayout.EAST);
```